# Принадлежность точки любому многоугольнику

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Не подскажите нормальный алгоритм определения принадлежности точки многоугольнику на С++

Comment: Важное уточнение: многоугольник выпуклый или без разницы какой?

Comment: Тут хорошо описано в статье [Реализации алгоритмов/Задача о принадлежности точки многоугольнику](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83)

Answer (score 7):

Для произвольного многоугольника. Метод не помню как называется (что-то там про луч, "метод трассировки луча", если я не ошибаюсь), идея в том, чтобы из точки провести луч в любую сторону (например вправо горизонтально) и посчитать количество пересечений со сторонами многоугольника, если их нечетное количество - то точка принадлежит многоугольнику. Единственно, нужно учесть особые случаи типа прохождения луча через вершину и стороны лежащие на луче.

Comment: @insolor, через вершину - считать за 2 пересечения

Comment: @paulgri, если точка внутри и луч выйдет через вершину, то будет два пересечения, но точка-то внутри. С другой стороны, возможны случаи что луч проходит через вершину "снаружи" (сходящиеся стороны многоугольника находятся по одну сторону от луча), тогда нужно считать как два пересечения. В общем, уберу "считать одним пересечением", тут нужно проверять именно расположение сходящихся в вершине сторон относительно луча.

Comment: @insolor, да, действительно, если стороны по одну сторону от луча, то за 2 пересечения, если по разные - за 1 пересечение. надо все возможные варианты рассматривать.

Answer (score 6):

В случае выпуклого многоугольника без "дырок" внутри алгоритм будет такой:

1. Подсчитать площадь многоугольника - допустим `SM`
2. Соединить точку со всеми вершинами многоугольника - в итоге получится N треугольников с основаниями сторон многоугольника и вершиной в нашей точке
3. Подсчитать сумму площадей полученных треугольников - допустим `SN`
4. Если `SN` > `SM` - значит точка лежит за пределами многоугольника, иначе внутри.

Answer (score 1):

Все необходимые инструменты (классы) для решения этой задачи находятся тут http://algolist.manual.ru/maths/geom/belong/poly2d.php 
Именно функция **pointInPolygon** проверять находиться ли точка в пределах многоугольники, но в качестве аргумента она должна получить объекты класса **Point** и **Polygon**, которые тебе надо взять отсюда http://algolist.manual.ru/maths/geom/datastruct.php

Comment: Сайт полезный, но алгоритмы, описанные там, все-таки ценнее, чем реализация на конкретном языке программирования.