# Лежит ли точка в полигоне? Решение, без самодельного велосипеда. (System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath)

Tags: c#

Нужно взяв `n` точек типа `Point` "нарисовать" замкнутый закрашенный полигон. И если определенная точка на "холсте" зарисована, то соответствующий элемент массива `bool[,]` приобретает значение `true`.

Привожу код, который, как мне кажется, должен-бы выполнять эту задачу. Но разумеется мне только кажется и в результате я получаю пустой "холст".

```
//точки масива
List<Point> ps = new List<Point>();
ps.Add(new Point(10, 0));
ps.Add(new Point(0, 0));
ps.Add(new Point(0, 10));
//не понял для чего GraphicsPath требует byte [] types
List<byte> ppt = new List<byte>();
ppt.Add(0);
ppt.Add(0);
ppt.Add(0);

//System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath
GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath(ps.ToArray(), ppt.ToArray());
//попытка замкнуть контур
gp.Flatten();

//переменная, ради которой было произведено все вышенаписанное
bool[,] bmp = new bool[11, 11];
for (int x = 0; x < 11; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < 11; y++)
        if (gp.IsVisible((float)x, (float)y))
            bmp[x, y] = true;
        else
            bmp[x, y] = false;

//следующий код только для визуализации
Bitmap visual = new Bitmap(11, 11);
for (int x = 0; x < 11; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < 11; y++)
        if (bmp[x, y])
            visual.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red);
visual.Save("bmp.png");
```

Думал сделать [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/282877/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83). Но, мне кажется, что в С# этот велосипед давно уже изобрели.

Можно, конечно и так полигон нарисовать

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);
Point[] points=...;
g.DrawPolygon(blackPen, points);
```

Но что-то мне подсказывает, что работа с `Image img = new Bitmap(x,y)` сильнее загрузит комп чем `bool [,] img = new bool [x,y]`

Answer (score 0):

Нашел в [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.addpath(v=vs.110).aspx) ответ почему у меня не работает рисование.

Нижеприведенная строка инициализации не создает полигона в `gp`

```
GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath(ps.ToArray(), ppt.ToArray());
```

Вместо этого нужно сделать так:

```
GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
//ВОТ так надо добавлять точки, чтобы получить полигон
gp.AddLines(ps.ToArray());
```

А вот полный код, который уже работает:

```
//точки масива
List<Point> ps = new List<Point>();
ps.Add(new Point(10, 0));
ps.Add(new Point(0, 0));
ps.Add(new Point(0, 10));
ps.Add(new Point(3, 1));

GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
gp.AddLines(ps.ToArray());

//перемення, ради которой было произведено все вышенаписанное
bool[,] bmp = new bool[11, 11];
for (int x = 0; x < 11; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < 11; y++)
        if (gp.IsVisible((float)x, (float)y))
            bmp[x, y] = true;
        else
            bmp[x, y] = false;

 //следующий код только для визуализации
 Bitmap visual = new Bitmap(11, 11);
 for (int x = 0; x < 11; x++)
     for (int y = 0; y < 11; y++)
         if (bmp[x, y])
             visual.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red);
 visual.Save("bmp.png");
```

Comment: так почему не работает-то?

Comment: потому что я делал так GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath(ps.ToArray(), ppt.ToArray()); а нашел что надо делать так gp.AddLines(ps.ToArray());

Comment: Добавь это описание в ответ, иначе не понятно, что именно изменилось

Comment: @Grundy: Потому что был указан неправильный `PathPointType`, судя по всему.